# VB.NET: Will the following list populate correctly?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I don't have access to VB.NET right now so I can't test this value:

`Dim lst As New List(Of String)(cookieValue.Split("$"c))`

i got this from another question , but was wondering if   A. The list will populate correctly and  B. What does the c represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    'test string
    Dim ipsum As String = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

    'split based on a string
    Dim lst_str As New List(Of String)(Strings.Split(ipsum, "in"))

    'split based on a char
    Dim lst_chr As New List(Of String)(ipsum.Split(New Char() {"$"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will.
It passes a string array to the [`List(IEnumberable<T>)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx).

`"$"c` is a [character literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sx7t66b%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Ok, is the cast to character literal needed if i know the value from the cookie is a string

Comment: It's not a cast.  It's a literal, just like `12` is a literal.  In C#, it would be `'$'`.  It has nothing to do with `cookieValue`; it's just a function parameter.

Comment: Also, what if the value is "ALF" instead of one character then i need to cast it as adifferent literal correct?

Comment: @kevin: Then it would have to be a string literal, since it's more than once character.  You can only use a character literal for one character, just like you can't do `'ALF'` in C#.

Comment: @kevin: There is no cast here. `"a"c` in VB.NET is a character literal. Do not confuse the syntax of a literal with a cast; they are two separate things.